# Applications manifest and librarys manifest in Android

Tags: android, manifest

I'm developing an application, with another project as my library.

What properties are merged in the manifest files?

Example - If the permissions are already specified in the Library's manifest file, do they need to be specified again in the applications manifest?

Also, if there is a service in the Library project, do I need to specify again manually in the Applications manifest too (additional to library's manifest).

Thanks

Comment: Cannot give you an answer right away, but why not try and see what permission application requires after install on device?!

Comment: i always declare everything in the main projects manifest. i know that activity declaration don't merge, i think it's because they aren't under the main project's application tag.

Comment: I asked a generic question. My implementation is different. I have to use Google's push (GCM) in the library project. There are several things which need to be there in the manifest, like broadcast receiver, services, etc. So not sure if they actually work when we put it in library's manifest

Answer (score 2):

There is a section of this page: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject that says you must (re)declare all of the bits of the library project that your application will be using in the manifest file.

> Declaring library components in the manifest file
>
> In the manifest file of the application project, you must add
>   declarations of all components that the application will use that are
>   imported from a library project. For example, you must declare     activity, service, receiver, provider, and so on, as well as permission, uses-library, and similar elements.
>
> Declarations should reference the library components by their
>   fully-qualified package names, where appropriate.

Personally, this seems redundant, but it may be because the app doesn't need to use all of the components of the library project, and the app shouldn't assume it will.